# Can I read and execute dynamic script file using webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I wondering if it possible to load script dynamic by webpack.

I create a nodejs application with webpack 5 configuration and typescript. (`ts-loader`).

And I want the application will be able to run module-script file that I'll give by reading the config file I created.

Something like that:

```
app.ts:
 const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./app.config.json', 'utf-8'));
 import(config.fn).then(m => { console.log({ m }); m.foo(); })
 
app.config.json:

 { fn: 'path/to/fn.js' }


path/to/fn.js:
exports = function foo() { console.log('in foo'); }
```

The problem is when I type the filename hard-coded in `import` it's works, but when i pass using variable it not work.

I wondering if webpack can do it? because I getting error:

```
uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './foo.js'
```

The code:

```
console.clear();

const foo = './foo.js';
// not works :(
import(foo).then((m) => {
  console.log({ m });
});

// not works :(
// require(foo).then((m) => {
//   console.log({ m });
// });

//works:
// import('./foo').then((m) => {
//   console.log({ m });
// });
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-webpack-js-org-omat6d?file=webpack.config.js,src%2Findex.js&terminal=build,start)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Dynamically loaded JavaDcript libraries are one of Javascript's greatest vulnerabilities.

Comment: yes. I update the question.